# Are there appearance CSS rules for webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch "handle" in iOS 5?

Tags: css, webkit, ios5

I have an element that happens to have both -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch and background-color: black so the "handle" that shows scroll position is very difficult to see. Are there -webkit CSS style rules that can alter the appearance (specifically the color) of that "handle" or am I stuck with the near-black coloring?

Comment: I looked in [this document](http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/documentation/appleapplications/reference/SafariCSSRef/Articles/StandardCSSProperties.html) but couldn't find any such properties.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the normal scrollbar styles, ex: `::-webkit-scrollbar`, `::-webkit-scrollbar-track`, `::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb` to alter the div that scrolls.

However, if the `-webkit-overflow-scrolling` is set to 'touch', the black default scrollbar will show up as well as your custom scrollbar.

But, if `-webkit-overflow-scrolling` is set to 'auto', it only your custom scrollbar shows. Not the most profound answer, but it's a start I think.

Comment: it will show custom scrollbar but its not gona do momentum scrolling!