# Custom scrollbars on iOS 5 webkit not working

Tags: css, ipad, ios5, webkit, scrollbar

I have a web page with a inner div that should be scrolled. That works fine in IOS5, but when I customize the scrollbars is still see the native one?

1. How can native scrollbars be removed when using custom ones?
2. The custom scrollbars seems also only to be updated after scroll complete, how to get them scroll when you are dragging the div?

What I've tried:

```
::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    border-radius: 10px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    border-radius: 10px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}

#info{
   overflow: scroll;
   -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
   height: 400px;
}
```

Comment: Did you check this question?: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7772376/are-there-appearance-css-rules-for-webkit-overflow-scrolling-touch-handle-in "if the -webkit-overflow-scrolling is set to 'touch', the black default scrollbar will show up as well as your custom scrollbar. But, if -webkit-overflow-scrolling is set to 'auto', it will only show your custom scrollbar"

Answer (score 0):

You have to remove
-webkit-overflow-scrolling:touch;
to disable that native scroll

Try this:

```
.webkitScrollClass {
    overflow-y:auto;
    overflow-x:hidden;
}

.webkitScrollClass::-webkit-scrollbar {
   -webkit-appearance: none;
}

.webkitScrollClass::-webkit-scrollbar:vertical {
    width: 6px;
}

.webkitScrollClass::-webkit-scrollbar:horizontal {
    height: 6px;
}

.webkitScrollClass::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    border-radius: 8px;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
}
```